# how to set focus on Devcomponents SuperGrid filter programmatically in dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

how to set focus on Devcomponents SuperGrid filter programmatically in dot net

When I press specific key My focus should be set to SuperGrid Filter Column 1 or Column 2.

We can enable filtering by setting the primaryGrid Property of Supergrid EnableFiltering & EnableCoulumneFilter to true

I have tried many things but all failed. Can any one help

[image]

Comment: Which language are you using? You should only tag the question with the language you want the answer in. Also have a look here [mcve]  You should also include the code that you've got so far. This is so that we can - hopefuly provide a working answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works for me.

```
Dim panel As GridPanel = LookupSuperGrid.PrimaryGrid 
LookupSuperGrid.PrimaryGrid.Filter.ActivateFilterEdit(panel.Columns("Account"))
```